# How to write lambda methods in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, functional-programming, lambda

How to write lambda methods in Objective-C ?

Comment: Late to the party but if anyone is still looking for official documentation on this, it can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Answer (score 95):

The concept of a lambda in Objective-C is now encapsulated with the idea of [Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/index.html) which are the equivalent of pass-by-reference functions. Of course, arguably one had that already in C with the idea of function pointers; blocks are just a way of also capturing local state (i.e. can be closures). In fact, blocks can also be used in other C languages as well (on Mac) - there's a proposal to make them part of the standard C syntax.

Here's an example of defining a lambda to multiply two numbers together:

```
int (^mult)(int, int) = ^(int a, int b) { return a*b; };
```

The first part declares a variable, of type `^int(int,int)` and then assigns it to the lambda expression (aka block) which returns the multiple of its two arguments. You can then pass that fn around, define it in other places etc; you can even use it in other functions.

Here's an example of defining a function, which when invoked, returns another function:

```
multiplyBy = ^(int a) { return ^(int b) { return b*a; }; };
triple = multiplyBy(3);
```

Note that you can intermix blocks with object types (usually using `id` as the object type) and many of the new Objective-C object data structures have some kind of block-level operation. GCD also uses blocks in order to pass in arbitrary events; however, note that GCD can also be used with function pointers as well.

Comment: Note also that block support has been ported to 10.5 and the iPhone OS with the Plausible Blocks project. http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/

Comment: Note that Blocks can be used in iOS 4, without the Plausible Blocks project.

Comment: +1 Excellent example with 'multiplyBy' AIBlue, thanks for demonstrating the flexibility of blocks so concisely.

Comment: ObjC blocks are similar to Smalltalk blocks, but it's unclear in Objective C how or whether it's even possible to define, implement, pass, accept, and call blocks of arbitrary types.

Comment: where do you declare the type of multiplyBy?

Comment: +1, but please don't use the word equivalent as you mention that you can close over the environment. Similar maybe. There is a huge gap between reference function. Runtime has to make work for that to happen and there is no chance you can use only reference function to make closure work.

Answer (score 29):

OS X 10.6 introduced blocks. See [AlBlue's answer for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943992/how-to-write-lambda-methods-in-objective-c/1810458#1810458).

If you're not using Snow Leopard, you can get something close to function composition using various other features.

Example using C function pointers:

```
void sayHello() {
    NSLog(@"Hello!");
}

void doSomethingTwice(void (*something)(void)) {
    something();
    something();
}

int main(void) {
    doSomethingTwice(sayHello);
    return 0;
}
```

Example using the command pattern:

```
@protocol Command <NSObject>
- (void) doSomething;
@end

@interface SayHello : NSObject <Command> {
}
@end

@implementation SayHello
- (void) doSomething {
    NSLog(@"Hello!");    
}
@end

void doSomethingTwice(id<Command> command) {
    [command doSomething];
    [command doSomething];
}

int main(void) {
    SayHello* sayHello = [[SayHello alloc] init];
    doSomethingTwice(sayHello);
    [sayHello release];
    return 0;
}
```

Example using a selector:

```
@interface SaySomething : NSObject {
}
- (void) sayHello;
@end

@implementation SaySomething
- (void) sayHello {
    NSLog(@"Hello!");    
}
@end

void doSomethingTwice(id<NSObject> obj, SEL selector) {
    [obj performSelector:selector];
    [obj performSelector:selector];
}

int main(void) {
    SaySomething* saySomething = [[SaySomething alloc] init];
    doSomethingTwice(saySomething, @selector(sayHello));
    [saySomething release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may have been true earlier, but the language now does have Blocks, which allow you to define real lambda expressions. Having said that, being able to pass around @selector()s as described above is a really useful mechanism in the Objective-C toolkit.

Comment: -1 for missing info about blocks, a central new feature, available in C, ObjC and C++, when using Apple's GCC in the new 10.6 version of OS X.

Comment: +1 for providing design patterns that may be preferable over blocks in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

I heard André Pang at NSConference talking about how blocks were going to be introduced with the next version of Objective-C.

This should allow functional programming.

Edit: Since Snow Leopard has been released, this is indeed the case. Objective-C now has [Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think you can write your anonymous function like this:

```
myBlock = ^( int number )
{
    return [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"Passed number: %i", number ];
};
```

For this, you need to add the following syntax:

```
NSString * ( ^ myBlock )( int );
```

In general, this link has written something for obj-c and obj-c++, I hope it will help you.

https://xs-labs.com/en/archives/articles/objc-blocks/

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. This doesn't add anything that the other answers don't already cover.

Comment: please read website